# Eclipse Juno for OS X Content Assist menu item selection from keyboard

Tags: eclipse

Something has changed from Indigo to Juno which has made me much less efficient:

- Content Assist menus items can't be cycled through using the "Line Down" shortcut anymore

Is there *anything* I can do to bring back the working behaviour?

Setup:

- OSX Mountain Lion (v10.8.3)
- Eclipse (v4.2.2, Build: M20130204-1200)
- Command: "Line Down", bound to: `CTRL-N`, when: In Windows
- Shortcut to invoke Content Assist: `OPTION-/`, when: In Dialogs and Windows

Note:

The exact same configuration, changing only Eclipse to Indigo (Version: 3.7.2; Build id: M20120208-0800) works *perfectly*. I have lots of muscle memory to undo if I can't fix this.. `:(`!

Reward:

**I want to set up a bounty for a solution to this but it says I have to wait 2 days before doing so..**

Reference links:

- [Navigating the Content Assist List in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615305/navigating-the-content-assist-list-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is go to

```
Window->Preferences->General->Keys
```

And from there you can change the binding of the commands you want to use. They are all there from copy and paste to running tests and refactoring. So if you assign several `Ctrl+N` you will get a list with all the commands you bound to and can click on the one you want.

Is this kinda what you had in mind?

Comment: This is what I had in mind (I even filed a bug for it): https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382839. Thanks for answering nonetheless..